# Cant enter negative numbers in textbox in c#

Tags: c#, string, textbox, formatting

in one of my programs, I have to accept numerical values from the user. i did the "double.parse" to convert the string in textbox to double. But during debugging, as soon as i enter the minus sign (-) the compiler shows error. The error is:

```
FORMAT EXCEPTION IS UNHANDLED
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

The code is:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Comment: the exception gets triggered as soon as the "-" gets entered...

Answer (score 8):

This is because you do it in `textBox1_TextChanged`: this is too soon to parse a `double`, it may be incomplete at that stage.

Try doing it when the end-user thinks that the entry is complete - for example, in the lost focus event handler. Alternatively, you can use [`double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) method to avoid exceptions on partial entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textbox1.Text != "" & textbox1.Text != "-")
        {
            p1 = double.Parse(textbox1.Text);
        }
    }
```

or this works too...